# Fetching data in range to process client-side (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Scripts I'm trying to return a string and I get an array.

The code is adapted from another answer: [Find Cell Matching Value And Return Rownumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565859/find-cell-matching-value-and-return-rownumber/32567126)

```
function updateValues(sheet) 
{  // loads named range "CalendarSettings" (on Reserved tab) into array dataSearch for later searching
   dataRangeSearch = sheet.getRange("CalendarSettings");
   dataSearch = dataRangeSearch.getValues().reduce(function (a, b) {return a.concat(b);});;
}
```

I was expecting that *dataSearch* would be a string, since I thought that *a.concat(b)* would result in a string.

"CalendarSettings" is a named range. Here is a screenshot of what the named range contains.[image: Named Range: CalendarSettings]

And here's a screenshot of a msgBox showing the contents of the variable dataSearch.[image: Contents of dataSearch]

This looks like an array to me, and it behaves like an array in terms of how it is accessed.  But what confuses me is that *a.concat(b)* I thought would be a string.

Comment: Can you provide a sample values of `dataRangeSearch.getValues()` and the result you want?

Comment: I don't think that there is a method sheet.getRange(string) unless the string is the A1Notation for a range.

Comment: If "CalendarSettings" is a named range then that would be `sheet.getRangeByName("CalendarSettings").getValues();`

Answer (score 0):

Strings and Arrays in JavaScript both have `.concat()` methods - using `.concat()` on two arrays will return an array, and on two strings will return a string.

You can turn an array into a string with `.toString()`:

```gas
dataSearch = dataRangeSearch.getValues().reduce(function (a, b) {return a.concat(b).toString();});;
```