# Function that takes in a date works but it cannot find the needed cell

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script

I've created this function to go through my column instead of the row following this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565859/find-cell-matching-value-and-return-rownumber)

The function:

```
function findDateInColumn(date, sheetName)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dateColumnVals = sheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues();
  Browser.msgBox("Date value is: " + date);
  for(let i = 0; i < dateColumnVals.length; i++)
  {
    for(let j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
      var cellDate = dateColumnVals[i][j];
      var inputDate = new Date(date);
      if(cellDate.toDateString() === inputDate.toDateString())
      {
        Browser.msgBox("cell column row is:" + (i+3));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The function goes through the values correctly and displays the correct date, but when it comes to comparing it, it doesn't find the date.

Here is the output of the cellDate and inputDate:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFJKq.png)

**Edit:**

The loop works correctly with august dates but not october

[Cell Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hhvb.png)

Comment: About `The function goes through the values correctly and displays the correct date, but when it comes to comparing it, it doesn't find the date.`, I thought that in this case, when you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue, it might help users understand of the reason for your current issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Your screenshot dates are not equal.

Comment: @TheMaster this shows the way data looks like in the cellDate and InputDate variables, I will update the screenshot to reflect it better.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, when I put the values of 01.08.2023 it worked correctly. I think it didn't work with the september date because of the blank space in the template sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the column had spaces. When the loop reached the empty space it tried to check the cellDate for Date value which it didn't have, so it worked only with one month but not with the other. Adding a simple value check fixed the issue, final code:

```
function findDateInColumn(date, sheetName)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dateColumnVals = sheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues();
  Browser.msgBox("Date values length" + dateColumnVals.length);
  for(let i = 0; i < dateColumnVals.length; i++)
  {
    for(let j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
      var cellDate = dateColumnVals[i][j];
      var inputDate = new Date(date);
      if(cellDate)
      {
        if(cellDate.toDateString() === inputDate.toDateString())
        {
          Browser.msgBox("cell column row is:" + (i+3));
        }  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the dates numerically:

```
function findDateInColumn(date = new Date(), sheetName = "Sheet0") {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var vs = sh.getRange("A2:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var dv = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()).valueOf()
  Browser.msgBox("Date: " + date);
  for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    let dt = new Date(vs[i])
    var tdv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
    if (dv == tdv) {
      Browser.msgBox("cell column row is:" + (i + 2));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

My Data:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 |
| 2 | 10/8/2023 |
| 3 | 10/9/2023 |
| 4 | 10/10/2023 |
| 5 | 10/11/2023 |
| 6 | 10/12/2023 |
| 7 | 10/13/2023 |
| 8 | 10/14/2023 |
| 9 | 10/15/2023 |
| 10 | 10/16/2023 |
| 11 | 10/17/2023 |

My result was line 8